# How do I center a div between two other divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS, and currently I have a right div, and a left div. I'm trying to put one between them and when I do, it'll move the right div slightly down. Here's what I have in CSS right now:

```css
.left {
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  border:3px solid black;
  float:left;
  border-top-right-radius:15px;
  border-top-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
  background-color:aliceblue;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.center{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}


.right{
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  border:3px solid black;
  float:right;
  border-top-right-radius:15px;
  border-top-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
  background-color:aliceblue;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  
}
```

```html
  <div class="left">
     </div>

 <div class="center">
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
    </div>
```

So what I'm asking is, how can I keep the center div in the middle, and keep both the left and right divs in their place and not move up/down?

Comment: you should make center div position absolute.Add `position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;` styles to `.center` class. see my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you float left the middle div and give a margin left to the same middle div, It is not always in the middle when screen size is changed. So you have to set middle div position absolute and make it always in the middle for all screen sizes. You can make anything make center by setting position absolute and giving left:0; right:0; margin:auto; css properties. So Make center div position absolute and add left:0px; right:0px; css styles.So add new styles for .center class.

```
.left {
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  border:3px solid black;
  float:left;
  border-top-right-radius:15px;
  border-top-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
  background-color:aliceblue;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.center{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}


.right{
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  border:3px solid black;
  float:right;
  border-top-right-radius:15px;
  border-top-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
  background-color:aliceblue;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}
```

```html
  <div class="left">
     </div>

 <div class="center">
    </div>

    <div class="right">
    </div>
```

Comment: Why does this change anything? Can you expound on your answer?

Comment: I explained above what I changed.

Comment: Down vote not mine. That being said, you did just provide some code, without explaining why it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the order of the divs:

```css
.left {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  float: left;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.center {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.right {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  float: right;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
<div class="center">
</div>
```

From the [W3C's Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> Content [that comes after the floated element] flows down the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a right-floated box.

Since you want the center div to be right of the left-floated div and left of the right-floated div, it should be placed after *both* divs in the HTML.

Or keep the divs the way they are and adjust the top margin on the right div:

```css
.left {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  float: left;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.center {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.right {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  float: right;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
</div>

<div class="center">
</div>

<div class="right">
</div>
```

A negative top margin offsets the effect of the float pushing the box down.

Comment: Why does this change anything? Can you expound on your answer?

Comment: @tjons What do you mean why does this change anything? The examples clearly show the result that the OP requested, with the divs aligned and the middle div centered.

Comment: I originally commented before @BSMP added the additional information. I'm beginning to become concerned about code-only (or almost-code-only) answers on SO, although I'm guilty of it myself. We need to be careful of not slipping into the trap of solving others problems while not helping them learn how to solve their own

Answer (score 0):

You can also add negative margin to center div.

```css
.left {
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  border:3px solid black;
  float:left;
  border-top-right-radius:15px;
  border-top-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
  background-color:aliceblue;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.center{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom: -100px;
}


.right{
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  border:3px solid black;
  float:right;
  border-top-right-radius:15px;
  border-top-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
  background-color:aliceblue;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
 </div>

 <div class="center">
</div>

<div class="right">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough data about your desired outcome here but why not float all three divs to the left?

Update:
You could use flexbox depending on your browser support. 
Put your divs into a container and set the container display to flex.

```
.container { display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; align-items: flex-start; }
```

Comment: If I were to float all 3 divs to the left, would I use any positioning or margins to put center and right to their desired positions and make it so they stay in the same place despite the page size?

Comment: That's just it. You didn't specify what you wanted other than three divs across. If you need something more than you may need a different solution.